# How to pass environment variables to a php script in windows

Tags: php, windows, command-line-arguments, php-resque

I'm just a starter in command line applications. I want to know how I can be able to pass environment variables to a php script running in the command line on windows 7 machine.

I want to do something similar to this:

`QUEUE=notification VVERBOSE=1 php resque.php`

Thank you for help..!

Comment: You can use php's `putenv()`

Comment: I thought putenv() could be possible inside the script itself, but in this case I want to pass them when invoking the script. The process for unix and osx users is described in this link:[link] (http://kamisama.me/2012/10/12/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-4-managing-worker/), but when I try that in windows it tells me the environment command QUEUE is not recognized

Comment: I some how think there is a way around this while using windows

Comment: Please consult the documentation of your operating system or search a website that is deidcated to computer use like [Super User - how to set ENV variable in windows CMD line](http://superuser.com/questions/212150/how-to-set-env-variable-in-windows-cmd-line)

Comment: @hakre thanks! for the link. It helped me and finally got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working.

On Unix systems you can set the environment variables on the same line invoking the script.

```
QUEUE=notification VVERBOSE=1 php resque.php
```

But for windows Os, you need to first set the environment  variable like this

```
SET QUEUE=notification

SET VVERBOSE=1
```

Then you invoke the script

```
php resque.php
```

Thank you to all who contributed...!